# fresh pybind11 install: two 'embed' tests failing

Tags: windows, pybind11

On Windows 10, using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 and Python 3.7, I get errors when I run the sanity check outlined by the pybind11 [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html):

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -A x64 ..
$ cmake --build . --config Release --target check
```

The output of the last command ends with this:

```
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\test_cmake_build\test_cmake_build.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\check.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\check.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\test_cmake_build\test_cmake_build.vcxproj" (default target) (7) ->
"C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\test_cmake_build\test_installed_embed.vcxproj" (default target) (8) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Tommy
 Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\test_cmake_build\test_installed_embed.vcxproj]

"C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\check.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\test_cmake_build\test_cmake_build.vcxproj" (default target) (7) ->
"C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\test_cmake_build\test_subdirectory_embed.vcxproj" (default target) (12) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\Tommy
 Herbert\source\pybind11-master\build\tests\test_cmake_build\test_subdirectory_embed.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:03:28.72
```

Should I be reporting this as a bug, or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: Does the output not contain the actual build error message further upstream the log? (Since it looks like a build, rather than execution, error, there's a good chance it's something local.)

Comment: @WimLavrijsen There is an error message upstream for each of the two failures, but neither gives any more information - they report the same stack traces I quoted and the trail ends with 'cmd.exe exited with code 1'. I found log files called installed_embed.log and subdirectory_embed.log, but they don't give any more clues that I can see.

Comment: I realised that I hadn't cloned the clang submodule. When I fixed that I found the same two errors plus a third earlier one!

error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [C:\Users\Tommy Herbert\source\pybind11-flat\build\tests\test_embed\cpptest.vcxproj]

Comment: I am also getting the same error, same setup, so it's not local, will add issue.

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/2090